# Looking for a word or phrase to describe 2 things that are moving toward each other, but never meet?

Tags: expressions

I was thinking about physics today and there was an idea where if 1 object splits into 2.

And If each object is moving away from each other at the speed of light.

And if just a moment after they split and start rushing away from each other if light/photons comes from each object moving towards each other, then the photons will never meet.

2 beams of light that are trapped a moment away from meeting each other forever.  Like a very sad love story :(

I wanted to know if there is a word or phrase that might describe the perpetual idea of trying to meet in the middle or be together, but never being able to succeed.

I thought about the word parallel like parallel lines because those never meet, but the problem is that they are next to each other and in this case I want to describe something where they are going from 2 separate points and try to connect in the middle.  I also thought anti-parallel which is closer to what I want but isn't quite right because you still run into the problem of the lines being next to each other.

So I am looking for any word, phrase or fictional character that is popular for a story of something similar.

Comment: I think that's just called politics.

Comment: Are you looking for ***asymptote***?

Comment: The word *asymptotic* comes to mind. Though not necessarily "head-on", *asymptotic trajectories*, for instance, are in a state of perpetual approach...

Comment: Wow @DanBron we were definitely writing our comments at the same time!

Comment: I am so tempted to comment on the errors in the physics but ... how about "converging unrequitedly"

Comment: If the relative velocity is zero, they're stationary wrt each other. Otherwise, they're converging (and will theoretically meet) or diverging. sojourner's suggested interpretation makes sense, however.

Comment: Please recognise, that has nothing at all to do with Engoish, nor any  language.

If you need help understanding what you're asking about, please look for a WWW  specialising not in language, but in physics.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for 'a word or phrase that might describe the perpetual idea of trying to meet in the middle or be together, but never being able to succeed', even 'fictional character that is popular for a story of something similar' I would suggest:

[Isabeau-Etienne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladyhawke)

They are two lovers cursed to be eternally apart though they are "always together"---by day Isabeau becomes a hawk, and by night Etienne becomes a wolf.

Answer (score 1):

A romantic metaphor would be:

> the sun and the sea at sunset, which seem so close and yet are so far apart

Answer (score -1):

> **Ships that pass in the night**, and speak each other in passing, only a signal shown, and a distant voice in the darkness; So on the ocean of life, we pass and speak one another, only a look and a voice, then darkness again and a silence.
>   — Henry Wadsworth Longfellow

Comment: Except the ships in the question never meet or pass. (Although, in fact, they would. The physics is all wrong!)